# Decomposing Time Series using STL gives error

Tags: python, pandas, forecasting

My code

```
stl_fcast = forecast(nottem_stl, steps=12, fc_func=seasonal_naive, seasonal = True)
```

Error Msg

```
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-39c1ef0e911d> in <module>
      1 stl_fcast = forecast(nottem_stl, steps=12, fc_func=seasonal_naive,
----> 2                      seasonal = True)
      3 
      4 stl_fcast.head()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stldecompose/stl.py in forecast(stl, fc_func, steps, seasonal, **fc_func_kwargs)
    102 
    103     # forecast index starts one unit beyond observed series
--> 104     ix_start = stl.observed.index[-1] + pd.Timedelta(1, stl.observed.index.freqstr)
    105     forecast_idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(freq=stl.observed.index.freqstr,
    106                                     start=ix_start,

pandas/_libs/tslibs/timedeltas.pyx in > pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta.__new__()
ValueError: Units 'M' and 'Y' are no longer supported, as they do not represent unambiguous timedelta values durations.
```

This code used to work in older versions of Pandas - 0.25.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your problem, a minimal dataframe for reproducing this issue, and some information about the method forecast, which you are calling? However, it seems that the problem is that you use month or year as units in timedelat. Try to use weeks or days.

Comment: I'm trying to create a forecast based on Seasonal and Trend decomposition with the following

I'm calling `from stldecompose import forecast
stldecompose.forecast_funcs import (naive, drift, mean, seasonal_naive)`


Dataset is the monthly seasonal ave temp of Nottingham UK from - https://www.statista.com/statistics/322658/monthly-average-daily-temperatures-in-the-united-kingdom-uk/